# Error could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a column which does not want to change from object to float. The data from the xlsx file is always presented the same (as a number), but somehow only this column is seen as object.

The numbers in the column represent percentage using point(.) as a decimal placement.

```
xls3[' Vesturland'] = xls3[' Vesturland'].astype(float)
```

does not work. There is no special characters to replace (eg.`str.replace()`), I have tried that as well.

I dare not to use

```
xls3[' Vesturland'] = pd.to_numeric(xls3[' Vesturland'])
```

because it changes all floats to `NaN` and the whole column is percentage values.

The only thing I can think of is that the number of decimals is not consistent, but that shouldn't really matter, or does it? I put a red arrow on the column I want to change to float.
[image]

I only get this error when I try to convert to float `Error could not convert string to float: ''` and searching for it on my specific problem has not given any results yet.

Comment: `len([x for x in xls3[' Vesturland'] if x == ''])` gives 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I ended up opening the excel sheet, deleted about 10 rows below the last data input. Then I unfroze rows/column, read it into Jupyter Notebook again and now **ALL OF THE DATA IS FLOAT**. I don't know which did the trick, but this is resolved now.
Thank you all that helped me here for your time and your attempts to solve this.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case the last column got an object in it with no data assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

You have empty strings in your `pd.Series`, which cannot be readily converted to a `float` data type. What you can do is check for them and remove them. An example script is:

```
import pandas as pd

a=pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'],['2.42','','3.285']]).T
a.columns=['names', 'nums']

a['nums']=a['nums'][a['nums']!=''].astype(float)
```

Note: if you try to run `a['nums']=a['nums'].astype(float)` before selecting non-empty strings the same error that you've mentioned will be thrown.

Comment: I have no missing or empty line, at least can't pandas find it, all `len([x for x in xls3[' Vesturland'] if x == ''])`, `xls3[' Vesturland'].isnull().sum()` and `xls3[' Vesturland'].isna().sum()` give 0 in result

Comment: Try measuring the length of each string entry, something like: `len_c = xls3[' Vesturland'].str.len().to_numpy()`, followed by `len_c.sort()`. As long as the top elements are 0 in that array, then there are empty strings in there.

Comment: `len_c = xls3[' Vesturland'].str.len().to_numpy()` followed by `len_c.sort()` gives no output, I ran the cell twice to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

First use this line to obtain the current dtypes:

```py
col_dtypes = dict([(k, v.name) for k, v in dict(df.dtypes).items()])
```

Like so:

```py
xls3 = pd.read_csv('path/to/file')
col_dtypes = dict([(k, v.name) for k, v in dict(xls3.dtypes).items()])
print(col_dtypes)
```

Copy the value that is printed.
It should be like this:

```
{'Date': 'object', 'Karlar': 'float64', 'Konur': 'float64', ' Vesturland': 'object', ...}
```

Then, for the column which whose datatype you know isn't object, change it to the required type ('int32', 'int64', 'float32' or 'float64')
Example:
The datatypes might be detected as:

```
{'Date': 'object', 'Karlar': 'float64', 'Konur': 'float64', ' Vesturland': 'object', ...}
```

If we know  `Vesturland` is supposed to be Float, then we can edit this to be:

```
col_dtypes = {
    'Date': 'object', 'Karlar': 'float64', 'Konur': 'float64', 
    ' Vesturland': 'float64', ...
}
```

Now, with this snippet you can find the non-numeric values:

```py
def clean_non_numeric_values(series, col_type):
    illegal_value_pos = []
    for i in range(len(series)):
        try:
            if col_type == 'int64' or col_type == 'int32':
                val = int(series[i])
            elif col_type == 'float32' or col_type == 'float64':
                val = float(series[i])
        except:
            illegal_value_pos.append(i)
            # series[i] = None # We can set the illegal values to None 
            # to remove them later using xls3.dropna()
    return series, illegal_value_pos



# Now we will manually replace the dtype of the column Vesturland like so:
col_dtypes = {
    'Date': 'object', 'Karlar': 'float64', 'Konur': 'float64', 
    ' Vesturland': 'float64'
}

for col in list(xls3.columns):
    if col_dtypes[col] in ['int32', 'int64', 'float32', 'float64']:
        series, illegal_value_pos = (
            clean_non_numeric_values(series=xls3[col], col_type=col_dtypes[col])
        )
        xls3[col] = series
        print(illegal_value_pos)
        if illegal_value_pos:
            illegal_rows = xls3.iloc[illegal_value_pos]
            # This will print all the illegal values.
            print(illegal_rows[col])
```

Now you can use this information to remove the non-numeric values from the dataframe.

Warning: Since this uses a for loop, it is slow but it will help you to remove the values you don't want.

Comment: I am not working with a dictionary. just a columns from excel sheet. And the values are unemployment percentages for one section of my country. My biggest question is why pandas takes this only column as object but not float like the rest of the columns.

Comment: Sorry, the first line works wonders, and I see that only column as an object, but for some reason it just will not change it to float by any means.

Comment: Run the second function to check if there are any values in the column that aren't float. 

Also, I wrote `df` as that is usually the name people use. In your case, you'll want to replace every `df` with `xls3`.

Pandas will only classify the column as object if there are some values that cannot be type cast to float or int.

If you find any such string values, Uncomment `series[i] = None` and then use dropna() to remove those rows.

Comment: yeah, I used xlsX for each cheat from the excel. I managed to get this working by running the first command `col_dtypes = dict([(k, v.name) for k, v in dict(df.dtypes).items()])
print(col_dtypes)` and then I did `df[' Vesturland'] = 'float64'` and now everything in my dataframe is float :D

Comment: Haha. You need to improve your pandas skills first. `df[' Vesturland'] = 'float64'` will replace every value in the entire column with 'float64'.

Read my answer again. I'm telling you to only replace the value of `col_dtypes` with the correct data type -- not to set `df[' Vesturland'] = 'float64'`

Comment: That is why I am doing this, to learn pandas :D I knew I would bump into something. 
How would I change the `col_dtypes` value to float?? Basically every answer I find tells me to do `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` which is not what I am trying to do

Comment: I just did the whole snipplet, and I got an interesting result
`[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[120]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-a9b087fc8a86> in <module>
     53         print(illegal_value)
     54         if illegal_value:
---> 55             illegal_rows = xls3.iloc[illegal_value[col]]
     56             print(illegal_rows[col])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` Not sure what this means

Comment: Please run it exactly, debug and understand what I've written. In `xls3.iloc[illegal_value[col]]`, `illegal_value_pos` is a list of all the values in that column that are not numeric. I guess you renamed `illegal_value_pos` to `illegal_value` and then tried to get `illegal_value[col]` which won't make sense as the `illegal_value` is a list of row numbers (list of integers).
The code above has found out that at row number 120, your column ` Vesturland` has a string value. Please check row number 121 on your excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
len([x for x in xls3[' Vesturland'] if x == ' '])
```

sometimes it can be blank go to your CSV file open it from excel and check is `ctrl+shift+l` filter and blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you do `for i in range 0,len(tablename)`

and you need `len(tablename)-1`

because you start at 0?

Comment: `range`'s upper bound is exclusive.

Comment: It was that I had "invisible" data in the excel, so deleting that did the trick.